# Could we please edit our landing page / welcome note

Tags: discussion, moderators, moderation, design

What if we start with the math.SE welcome note, and take it from there.

"Welcome!
This is a collaboratively edited question and answer site for people studying **robotics** at any level and professionals in related fields. It's 100% free, no registration required.

Got a question about the site itself? meta is the place to talk about things like what questions are appropriate, what tags we should use, etc."

Other ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We already have this, but you can only see it **if you aren't logged on**.

If you navigate to [robotics](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/) in a different browser (or using a new browser profile) then you see a welcome box saying the following:

> #### Welcome!
>
> This is a collaboratively edited question and answer site for **professional robotic engineers, hobbyists, researchers and students**. It's 100% free, no registration required.
>
> Got a question about the site itself? [meta](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/) is the place to talk about things like what questions are appropriate, what tags we should use, etc.
>
> [about »](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/about?mnu=1)    [faq »](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/faq?mnu=1)   [meta »](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/)

While on [meta](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/) says:

> #### Welcome!
>
> This site is for **discussion** about [Robotics - Stack Exchange](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/). You must have an account there to participate.
>
> [faq »](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/faq?mnu=1)

This is just the same as on other stack exchange sites.

Comment: Thanks! Thought I was logged in everywhere, turns out only here.